# Computed observable not updating value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm currently learning how to incorporate knockoutJS in my projects, however, I've run into an issue which has left me stumped.

I have a simple computed observable that returns the value of two concatenated strings. The issue I'm having is that the method returns the correct value when the view first loads, however, if I update one of the observables used in my function, the updated value is not displayed.

**index.cshtml**

```
@model KnockoutProjectt.Models.Register

<input type="text" data-bind="value: forename" />
<p data-bind="text: forename"></p>
<p data-bind="text: getFullName"></p>

@section Script {
  <script src="~/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
  <script>

  var options = {
      forename: '@Html.Raw(Model.Forename)',
      surname: '@Html.Raw(Model.Surname)',
      email: '@Html.Raw(Model.Email)'
  };

  var viewModel = init(options);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

  </script>
}
```

**scripts.js**

```
function init(options) {

  var viewModel = {
      forename: ko.observable(options.forename),
      surname: ko.observable(options.surname),
      email: ko.observable(options.email)
  }

  viewModel.getFullName = ko.computed(function () {
      return options.forename + ' ' + options.surname;
  });

  return viewModel;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the computed is based on the original values passed in on the `options` object, rather than the observables created from them.  You just need to update it to work from the observables:

```
viewModel.getFullName = ko.computed(function () {
    return viewModel.forename() + ' ' + viewModel.surname();
});
```